# fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'mfc110d.lib'

Tags: qt, opencv, visual-studio-2012, qt5, visual-c++-2012

I am currently developing a program in VS c++ 2012 ( Ultimate trial version). It uses 3rd part lib ( Qt5.1.1 x64 and openCV 2.4.5 ). When I try to build it it gives " fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'mfc110d.lib'". I tried to find this lib but it seems that it does not exist on my machine. This project was initially developed on a different machine. 
Have anyone met this problem before?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15330058/error-lnk1104-cannot-open-file-mfc90-lib

Comment: Should be there: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\atlmfc\lib\mfc110d.lib`

Comment: I know that it should be there but it's not. There are only atl*.lib and atl*.pdb files ( + amd64 and arm folders ) . I am using a trial version of VS Ultimate , could this be a problem ?

Comment: Some useful info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235264%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: Ok. Try to install "Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package".

Comment: I have had the Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package(x64) installed.

Comment: The debug libraries for MFC will not be in any Microsoft redistributable.

Comment: It's very curious to me why MFC is a dependency if you are using Qt and opencv.

Comment: Also I believe MFC may not be installed by default in VS2012.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved! Indeed, MFC was not installed by default. I had to go to Control Panel-> Uninstall a program -> Visual Studio 2012 right click -> Change . Then check Install MFC and that's it.

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Thx! Lifesaver.