# After upgrading from VS 2012 to VS 2013, error LNK1104: cannot open file 'mfc110d.lib'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, mfc

I've just upgraded from VS 2012 to VS 2013, installed the [Multibyte MFC Library for Visual Studio 2013](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=40770), and run the [Upgrade VC++ Compiler and Libraries](https://i.imgur.com/SBtzjgN.png) tool without incident.

When I compile my VC++ project, I'm getting the error:

```
Error   8   error LNK1104: cannot open file 'mfc110d.lib'   C:\Dev\batch.7.dev\MyProj\LINK  MyProj
```

Do I need to retarget MFC from v110 to v120?

I've looked at [fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'mfc110d.lib'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18630425) and that's covered, both VS 2012 and VS 2013 have MFC installed.

Comment: Yes.  Rebuild *all* of your projects so they'll use the 2013 version of MFC.  If you are using a 3rd party library then you'll have to ask them for an update.  If that's a problem then change the Toolset to v110 (not ideal).

Comment: @HansPassant Sorry if this is really basic, but how do I tell my VC++ project to use the 2013 version of MFC?  My googlings just tell me how to choose this when starting a new VC++ project.

Comment: It is automatic, the Toolset selects it.  You'll need to find the project or .lib you link that didn't get rebuilt.

Comment: @HansPassant I appreciate your replies, but I honestly don't understand what you're telling me to do.  Some part of this automatic process isn't doing the right thing, and I don't know how to correct it.

Comment: He's saying that something you depend on (ex: a library) might have been compiled on VS2012 and needs the 2012 version of MFC. Your solution is either to upgrade all the libraries (as in, go redownload them on their website and make sure they're compiled for VS2013) and if you can't do that, change the compiler version in the project settings